# How do I redirect to an absolute url in express js?

Tags: express

I would like to redirect to an absolute url like so

```
express.redirect('127.0.0.1:3000/page);
```

The problem is that this produces the following url:

> 127.0.0.1:3000/127.0.0.1:3000/page

How can I redirect to an absolute path as described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you need to add "//" in front of the redirect url to make express know it's absolute. Lucky I accidentally figured that out as it doesn't seem to appear in the docs.

A few examples to be clear:

```
res.redirect('//127.0.0.1:3000');
```

or

```
res.redirect('//www.tutaroo.com');
```

If you try something like

```
res.redirect('//http://www.tutaroo.com');
```

you will likely get redirect errors as it will try to look for

> https://https//www.tutaroo.com

so be careful with that.